# What is the purpose of @aws_subscribe annotation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, mqtt, aws-appsync, aws-iot

I am reading [realtime data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/real-time-data.html) documentation but do not understandwhat is the purpose of `@aws_subscribe`. Could somebody explain this in simple English? Examples about how subscriptions works with/without annotation will help a lot.

Comment: This creates subscriptions you can register that will be bound to specific mutations.  In some cases you may be using Graphql transformers that will generate operations. Below Rick highlights this mechanism, but what is happening is that when your graphql server runs this specific mutatio your client will receive a push (as you defined in your subscription).  Which is the realtime nature of @aws_subscribe

Answer (score 4):

Using the @aws_subscribe directive, you can declare the mutations a subscription is subscribed to. For example:

```
type Mutation {
  createPost(): Post
  editPost(): Post
  deletePost(): Post
}

type  Subscription {
  updatedPost(): Post
    @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["createPost","editPost","deletePost"])
}
```